# Not able to create Web service in C# (asmx) with POST method and input FormData

Tags: c#, json, web-services, post, asmx

Can you please provide me link, so I can follow it and create my first web service which will take data in form data and output in JSON with POST method. I am creating this service for both Android and iOS app.

**Note I am still using .net framework 4.0.**
Thanks in Advance.

Comment: That is a great question, but unfortunately too broad for StackOverflow.

Comment: @mjwills Thanks for your response. Can you please give me the any reference link for the same. I am really facing lot of problems

Comment: @ManishMahajan  Nice question , I am also waiting for the answer

Answer (score 1):

Create any rest API should work-[Try this sample project on codeproject.com](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/255684/Create-and-Consume-RESTFul-Service-in-NET-Framewor)

Comment: Thanks for your response. I will check and let you know